# kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.graphics.Bitmap

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm making an adaptation so that instead of opening the camera take an image of the gallery, but I'm having this error

SOLVED --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
error at line
   val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, this.imageUri) as Bitmap

log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: map.app, PID: 7359
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:3, request=1000, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/48/ORIGINAL/NONE/1141690198 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F48/ORIGINAL/NONE/1141690198} }} to activity {map.app/map.app.MainActivity}: kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.graphics.Bitmap
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4268)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.graphics.Bitmap
        at map.app.fragments.ReportFragment.onActivityResult(ReportFragment.kt:272)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7303)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4264)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
Application terminated.
```

code

```
fun openCamera() {
        try {
            val imageFile = createImageFile()
            val callCameraIntent =  Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            if(callCameraIntent.resolveActivity(activity.packageManager) != null) {
                val authorities = activity.packageName + ".fileprovider"
                this.imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, authorities, imageFile)
                callCameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)
                startActivityForResult(callCameraIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CODE)
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Could not create file!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

part error code line
error at line
   val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, this.imageUri) as Bitmap
Caused by: kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.graphics.Bitmap

```
  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            try {

                //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, this.imageUri) as Bitmap
                this.imgThumb!!.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                this.pictureTaken = true
            } catch (e:IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error loading image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        }
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun createImageFile(): File {
        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
        val imageFileName: String = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_"
        val storageDir: File = activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        if(!storageDir.exists()) storageDir.mkdirs()
        val imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir)
        imageFilePath = imageFile.absolutePath
        return imageFile
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must cast it to a nullable type instead of non nullable. Do the following:

```
val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, this.imageUri) as Bitmap?
```

Note that the `Bitmap?` instead of `Bitmap`

Comment: Thanks if possible check new error, i'm edited this post whit new error, thanks man.

Comment: @Davi please don't change your question. Leave it as it was and let the answer provided answer it. If you have updated code and a new question, post a new question. Changing the original question significantly causes confusion in the Q&A thread.

Comment: @madz If you can help, I have a problem, thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55969484/method-boolean-android-graphics-bitmap-compressandroid-graphics-bitmapcompres