# method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bitmap

I am having this error in my code, someone informs me how to solve it? Thank you to everyone who can help.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
        at map.app.fragments.ReportFragment.putImgToBytearray(ReportFragment.kt:177)
```

line error

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream)
```

code

```
private fun putImgToBytearray(): ByteArray {
    val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val drawable = this.imgThumb!!.drawable as BitmapDrawable
    val bitmap = drawable.bitmap
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream)
    return stream.toByteArray()
}
```

onActivityResult code

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


        try {

            //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
            val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, this.imageUri) as Bitmap?
            this.imgThumb!!.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
            this.pictureTaken = true
        } catch (e:IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error loading image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    }
}
```

method for select image from gallery. it's just an adaptation

```
fun openCamera() {
    try {
        val imageFile = createImageFile()
        val callCameraIntent =  Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        if(callCameraIntent.resolveActivity(activity.packageManager) != null) {
            val authorities = activity.packageName + ".fileprovider"
            this.imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, authorities, imageFile)
            callCameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)
            startActivityForResult(callCameraIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CODE)
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Could not create file!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you Verify that onActivityResult is working fine? If imgThumb has the image the you can use that bitmap directly for the byte array.

Comment: @Sunny yes it loads to thumb only does not display but load. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Sunny I added the method that I use to take the images from the gallery if I can check it I would be grateful.

Comment: Also try to use as much as relevant labels you can. So don't miss the android label to get more attentions from android guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet that `MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap` does not get the bitmap properly and returns null.

So if you remove the `?` in `MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, this.imageUri) as Bitmap?` you will get a runtime exception as your previous question asserts.

So change the cast to:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, this.imageUri) as Bitmap
```

To make sure you never get a null bitmap then com back to investigate `getBitmap` method

I have no idea what does the `createImageFile` method do, but I suggest you to simply do the following to test if it is working:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse("file://"+uri));
```

Finally I advice against of using of `MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap` at all.

See [Its deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#getBitmap(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri)). switch to image loading libraries or use  [ImageDecoder#createSource(ContentResolver, Uri)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageDecoder.html#createSource(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri))

There are guides in the mentioned link. Like this one:

```
public static Bitmap decodeBitmap (ImageDecoder.Source src)
```

Also make sure to do these kin of stuff in a worker thread.

Comment: hi, apparently it is trying to load the image but I get this msg, xml / path is correct what could be wrong?

W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /map.map.fileprovider/intent_images/JPEG_20190506_195537_4956550318512812108.jpg (No such file or directory)

Comment: I created a new post with more details about the problem, sorry bother you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56028367/i-am-getting-this-msg-speech-that-did-not-find-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Hi Dave, no problem at all! Sorry I tried multiple times to respond but was too busy. Now  that you've created a new post I'd take a look